# VF Page unable to show Custom Setting Value when accessed from Live Chat

Tags: liveagent, customsetting, visualforce

I have fetched certain data from Custom settings and used them in a VF Page.When the vf page is previewed it shows the values in the picklist of vf but when the vf is opened from Live Chat.It shows blank but has the picklist space,looks like the text is hidden.I have made the class without sharing still of no use.The profile from which live chat was opened has been added to the apex permission profile list.

Controller:

```
public without sharing class  CountryNameGeneratorController {
    //public List<String> countryNames { get; set; }

    public CountryNameGeneratorController() {
        getCountryNames();
    }

    public List<CountryNameMaster__c> getCountryNames() {
        //countryNames = new List<String>();

        List<CountryNameMaster__c> allCountries = new List<CountryNameMaster__c>();

        allCountries = [
            SELECT  CountryName__c
            FROM    CountryNameMaster__c
            ORDER BY CountryName__c ASC
        ];
        return allCountries ;
       // for(CountryNameMaster__c country : allCountries ) {
           // countryNames.add( new SelectOption( country.Id, country.CountryName__c ) );
        //}
    }
}
```

VF Page snippet:

```
 <div><label>Country*</label>
   <select name='liveagent.prechat:Country' id='Country' required="required">
   <option value="">---Please Select---</option>
   <apex:repeat value="{!CountryNames}" var="cont">
    <option value=""><apex:outputText value="{!cont.CountryName__c }" /></option>
</apex:repeat>



</select>
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:Country" value="Country__c" />
    </div>
```

It just shows Please Select with a big blank picklist.But when the Vf page is previewed it shows the correct data.